# Equivalent of C++'s sizeof(uint64Array) in C#?

Tags: c#, random

On this code : http://prng.di.unimi.it/xoshiro256plus.c
They do this :

```
static const uint64_t JUMP[] = { 0x180ec6d33cfd0aba, 0xd5a61266f0c9392c, 0xa9582618e03fc9aa, 0x39abdc4529b1661c };

 for(int i = 0; i < sizeof JUMP / sizeof *JUMP; i++)
```

What does **sizeof JUMP / sizeof *JUMP** means and how to port it to c# ?

**sizeof JUMP** seems to be **Marshal.Sizeof(JUMP)** according to
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.sizeof?view=netframework-4.8

But Marshal.Sizeof(*JUMP) cant be donne in safe mode and I cant use unsafe code.

And according to this page : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof **sizeof JUMP / sizeof *JUMP** return array's length.
So why not just put 4 instead as JUMP length is known ?

Thank.

Comment: If someone adds another element to the `JUMP` array its size will no longer be 4. The `sizeof`s are used to make sure you always have the correct length (which in C# is stored in the `Length` property of an array)

Comment: Why not just put `4`? Because magic constants are bad, and make it easy to break code by forgetting to update them. `sizeof array / sizeof *array` is a standard idiom in C and C++ for "give me the length of a declared array". The simple equivalent in C# is, of course, `array.Length` -- managed arrays track their length, arrays in C and C++ don't.

Comment: Ultimately: `.Length` and you're done; in particular, note that the JIT on modern runtimes recognizes the pattern `for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) { /* arr[i] */ }` and elides (removes) the bounds check in the `arr[i]` (as long as `arr` is a local variable (or possible a `readonly` field?) and isn't swapped at any point), on the basis that it knows the array can't change size ever

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why not just put 4 instead as JUMP length is known

because unlike C#'s arrays, you cannot simply access a `Length` property of an array in C++. Yes, 4 is the correct answer *today* but what if someone edits the array later and there are 3 or 5 entries? They have to remember to edit the `for` as well.

Answer (score 3):

> What does sizeof JUMP / sizeof *JUMP means and how to port it to c# ?

sizeof JUMP / sizeof *JUMP is the size in bytes of the total array divided by the size of the first array element. That gives you the length of the array.

It's the same as writing sizeof JUMP / sizeof JUMP[0]

In C# you just write "JUMP.Length"

```
for (int i = 0; i < JUMP.Length; i++)
{
}
```

On a sidenote, you do have limited sizeof capability in C#:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    long[] arr = new long[10];

    Console.WriteLine("" + Marshal.SizeOf(arr[0]));
```

So you can translate *JUMP to JUMP[0]

Comment: `Marshal.SizeOf` gives the size of an instance when marshaled to unmanaged code for P/Invoke calls. It is *not* equivalent to what `sizeof(type)` gives you, except when it coincidentally is (like it is for `long` -- but try `bool`). It is a common and insidious mistake to use `Marshal.SizeOf` in managed code, but it's wrong if the memory never leaves the managed world. .NET Core has [`Unsafe.SizeOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe.sizeof), which encapsulates `sizeof` without the need for an explicit `unsafe` block.